# ASP.NET MVC subsections

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is a master page with a simple menu at the top (MenuItem1, MenuItem2 and Administration) and a content area below. The first two entries are just links to HomeController actions which render views (which use the master page). With Administration there is a need to manage different kinds of objects (for example: users, groups, items, etc.) and it does not fit into one action idea. I know that it may be solved by adding the top menu "User Administration", "Group Administration", etc. (instead of a single menu item Administration) but I don't like the solution. I prefer to have have some subsections under Administration - a kind of submenu or tabs which are only visible when Administration has been selected. How to achieve it in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks in advance
Lukasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the usage of [Html.Action and Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helpers useful. They allow you to have completely separate child MVC life-cycle integrated into the main MVC pipeline.

Comment: Is there any best practice how to send information which section is the "selected" one?

Comment: @GUZ, you could pass parameters to those helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Areas. An area will give your the administration section from which you can create the different sub-sections. It also has its own routing table to modify.

[Quick little MS video on Areas.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2-areas)

Comment: After watching the video I have a feeling that areas are just to separate different parts of a website. I still don't know how to compose a view using the master page with administration subsection links and the chosen subsection.